# Why the extra statement in Rubymonk in Lesson "7.1 Iterate, Filtrate and Transform"

Tags: ruby, methods, return

In the below Rubymonk example, why is it:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject(0) do |accumulator, iterated|
  accumulator += iterated
  accumulator
end
```

and NOT

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject(0) do |accumulator, iterated|
  accumulator += iterated
  #accumulator
end
```

The results are the same are they not?  I think the last 'accumulator' line is unnecessary.

https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/44-collections/lessons/98-iterate-filtrate-and-transform#solution4313

Comment: Yes, but the operative line should be just `accumulator + iterated`.

Comment: Also, in Ruby 2.0+,  people use shorter version `[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].inject(&:+)`

Comment: Why? Programmer's prerogative? It's a tiny bit clearer what `inject` needs for people who don't know? The person writing the example wasn't that good at Ruby? As @CarySwoveland said, `accumulator + iterated` would be better but it masks the fact that `inject` needs the returned value to be the `accumulator`.

Comment: If you found either answer helpful, please select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use both as long as the return value of the block is `accumulator`. I think Rubymonk example is more explicit. If you take a look at the `custom_inject` example, you'll understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`) is a strange (but powerful) bird. If returns an object called the "memo". The value of the memo is typically a number, string, array or a hash, but it can be any ruby object.

The first block variable holds the value of the memo. As each element is passed into the block, the value of the memo is set equal to the result of previous block calculation. Suppose, for example, the block looks like this:

```
{ |memo,x| memo + x }
```

Assume further that the initial value of the memo is zero (I discuss that below) and the first value of `x` is `3`. Then since

```
memo + x #=> 0 + 3 => 3
```

`memo` is set equal to `3` and `x` is set equal to the next value passed to the block. Suppose that value is `4`. Then `memo` is updated to:

```
memo + x #=> 3 + 4 => 7
```

Now suppose the block is instead written:

```
{ |memo,x| memo += x }
```

Initially, `memo` equals zero and `x` equals 3. We therefore compute:

```
memo += x #=> memo = memo + 3 => 0 + 3 => 3
  #=> 3
```

That is, the value `memo` is now `3'. As before,`memo`is updated to equal the value of the block calculation, which we just saw was`3`.  When`x=4`,`memo`is computed in the block to be`7`, and then`memo`is set to that same value (`7`) because that was the result of the block calculation.

As you see, when the block contains `memo += x`, the value of `memo` is computed *twice*: first within the block calculation; second, it is updated to equal the value of the block calculation, which is the value of `memo` just calculated. So the calculation goes like this:

```
memo = 0, x = 3, memo #=> 3 (after memo += 3), them memo is set to 3
memo = 3, x = 4, memo #=> 7 (after memo += 4), them memo is set to 7
```

Aside: since memo is assigned the value the block calculation, the last line (`tot`) of:

```
arr.inject(0) do |tot,x|
  tot += x
  tot
end
  #=> 6
```

is redundant.

In summary, `{ |memo,x| memo+x }` and `{ |memo,x| memo += x }` produce the same result, but the former is more efficient because it computes `memo` only once for each element passed to the block.

What about the initial value of `memo`? If the method that passes objects to the block has an argument, that value of that argument is the initial value of `memo`. If it has no argument, `memo` is set equal to first value passed to the block and block calculations begin when the next element is passed to the block. Suppose, for example, we wish to sum the elements of:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

We could write:

```
arr.inject(0) { |tot,x| tot+x }
  #=> 6
```

or

```
arr.inject    { |tot,x| tot+x }
  #=> 6
```

Here we get the same result, so does it matter which form we use? Suppose:

```
arr = []
```

then:

```
arr.inject(0) { |tot,x| tot+x }
  #=> 0
```

and

```
arr.inject    { |tot,x| tot+x }
  #=> nil
```

So if `inject` may be invoked on an empty array, use the form that produces the result you want. Here that probably would be the first form in most cases.

There is a shorter form we could use here:

```
arr.inject(0,:+)
  #=> 0
arr.inject(:+)
  #=> nil
```

but you should perhaps leave that for another day.